# How to solve this warning "Decision variable "IL#0#0#0#0#0#0" has never been used by the engine."?

Tags: networking, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I have been working on the mathematical model for a long time and now I could improve it. In this model we have nodes and edges and the flows that pass through these nodes according to the topology. We also have network functions that we use to create two length chains. I don't know how to define two dependent indices. For example, in constraint 1 and the following constraints, the two indices j and nj[j] are dependent on each other. I don't know if I defined this dependency correctly or not? If you can check my code and tell me where I made a mistake or give me an example, I would be grateful. Now, My code works. But I get the error that I have not used the decision variable IL for 99 times, and also the 3, 4 objective functions always give zero value I don't think this can be true. Dear Mr Fleischer, I have asked you several times questions and I am very grateful for your kindness, but if you can, please help me this time as well. Thanks in advance.

[This is the topology image, which I determined flows and their routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFE3R.png)

.mod file

```
using CPLEX;

//Total nodes number. 
range Nodes = 1..9;
//................................................................................

//Total links number
//two_directed

tuple edge{
key int node_out;
key int node_in;
};
{edge} L with node_out, node_in in Nodes = {<1,3>, <3,1>, <2,3>, <3,2>, <3,4>, <4,3>, <3,5>, 
<5,3>, <3,6>, <6,3>, <4,5>, <5,4>, <4,6>, <6,4>, <4,8>, <8,4>, <5,6>, <6,5>, <6,7>, <7,6>, 
<6,9>, <9,6>};

{edge} Lin[Nodes] = [{<3,1>},//node1
                    {<3,2>},//node2
                    {<1,3>, <2,3>, <4,3>, <5,3>, <6,3>},//node3
                    {<3,4>, <5,4>, <6,4>, <8,4>},//node4
                    {<3,5>, <4,5>, <6,5>},//node5
                    {<3,6>, <4,6>, <5,6>, <7,6>, <9,6>},//node6
                    {<6,7>},//node7
                    {<4,8>},//node8
                    {<6,9>}];//node9

  {edge} Lout[Nodes] = [{<1,3>},//node1
                        {<2,3>},//node2
                        {<3,1>, <3,2>, <3,4>, <3,5>, <3,6>},//node3
                        {<4,3>, <4,5>, <4,6>, <4,8>},//node4
                        {<5,3>, <5,4>, <5,6>},//node5
                        {<6,3>, <6,4>, <6,5>, <6,7>, <6,9>},//node6
                        {<7,6>},//node7
                        {<8,4>},//node8
                        {<9,6>}];//node9
     //.......................................................................................

       //Flows and their routes
       tuple cflow{
        int node1;
        int node2;
        }
      {cflow} F with node1,node2 in Nodes = {<1,2>, <1,3>, <1,4>, <1,5>, <1,6>, <1,7>, 
                                             <1,8>, <1,9>, <2,1>, <2,3>, <2,4>, <2,5>, <2,6> 
                                             <2,7>, <2,8>, <2,9>, <3,1>, <3,2>, <3,4>, <3,5>, 
                                             <3,6>, <3,7>, <3,8>, <3,9>, <4,1>, <4,2>, <4,3>, 
                                             <4,5>, <4,6>, <4,7>, <4,8>, <4,9>, <5,1>, <5,2>, 
                                             <5,3>, <5,4>, <5,6>, <5,7>, <5,8>, <5,9>,
                                             <6,1>, <6,2>, <6,3>, <6,4>, <6,5>, <6,7>, <6,8>, 
                                             <6,9>, <7,1>, <7,2>};

   {int} Routes[F] = [{1,2}, {1,3}, {1,3,4}, {1,3,5}, {1,3,6}, {1,3,6,7}, {1,3,4,8}, 
               {1,3,6,9},{2,3,1}, {2,3}, {2,3,4}, {2,3,5}, {2,3,6}, {2,3,6,7}, {2,3,4,8}, 
               {2,3,6,9}, {3,1}, {3,2}, {3,4}, {3,5}, {3,6}, {3,6,7}, {3,4,8}, {3,6,9}, 
               {4,3,1}, {4,3,2}, {4,3}, {4,5}, {4,6}, {4,6,7}, {4,8}, {4,6,9}, 
               {5,3,1}, {5,3,2}, {5,3}, {5,4}, {5,6}, {5,6,7}, {5,4,8}, {5,6,9},
               {6,3,1}, {6,3,2}, {6,3}, {6,4}, {6,5}, {6,7}, {6,4,8}, {6,9}, 
               {7,6,3,1}, {7,6,3,2}];

 //landa
 float landa[f in F]=(0.5+rand(2))/2;
 //.....................................................  

 //VNFs
 {string} V = {"P", "F", "I", "D", "N"};
 //...........................................................

 //Random Chains
 int n=card(V);
 int m=2;

 range r=1..n;

    // scripting way that will get m times 1
    range subr=1..m;
    int t[j in subr][f in F]=1+rand(n+1-j);
    {int} setn[f in F]=asSet(r);

    int x2[j in r][F];

    execute
    {
    for(var j in subr)for (var f in F)
    {
       var e=t[j][f];
       var e2=Opl.item(setn[f],e-1);
       x2[e2][f]=1;
       setn[f].remove(e2);  }}
    
 {int} result[f in F]={j | j in r:x2[j][f]==1};
    
 {string} Chains4[f in F]=union (j in result[f]) {item(V,j-1)};
    
 {string} Chains[f in F]={item(Chains4[f],i-1) | i in 1..card(Chains4[f])};

 assert forall(f in F) forall(ordered j,i in Chains[f]) j!=i;

 //length Chains
 int J[f in F] = card(Chains4[f]); 
 //......................................................................................

//Resources
int Cpunode[n in Nodes]=...; //the number of cores at each node.
int cpuvnf[v in V]=...; //an instance of type v may need multiple cores.

int Memnode[n in Nodes]=...; //the amount of memory at each node.
int memvnf[v in V]=...; //an instance of type v may need amount of memory.

//bandwidth
float u[v in V][n in Nodes]=...; 

//transmission rate.
float C[l in L]=...; 

//Delays
float Dvn[v in V][n in Nodes]=...; //denote the expected nodal delay for type v NF at node n.
float Dlink[l in L]=...;
float Dflow[f in F] =...;

float M=100; //a big amount
//.....................................................................................

  int nj[0..3];//I don't know is it correct or not???????????
  //........................................................................................

  //MAIN DECISION VARIABLES
  dvar int I[v in V][Nodes][f in F][j in 1..2] in 0..1;
  //denotes that an NF instance v hosted at node n is used by the j-th service on the service 
  chain of flow f.

  dvar int IL[l in L][f in F][1..2][Nodes][2..3][Nodes] in 0..1;
  //denotes that link l is used 
  by flow f to route from the j-th to (j + 1)-th NF service, hosted at node nj and nj+1.

  dvar int Y[v in V][n in Nodes]; 
  //represents the number of NF type v instances that are 
  hosted at node n.

  //New decision variables
  dvar int G[ n in Nodes] in 0..1; //counts the number of Nodes.
  dvar int S[l in L] in 0..1;

  //Decision variables related  with non linear equations
  dvar int z[l in L][f in F][1..2][Nodes][2..3][Nodes][V] in 0..1;
  //......................................................................................

  //Related  with floor function
  dexpr float x[f in F] = sum(v in V, n in Nodes, j in 1..2) I[v][n][f][j] / J[f];
  dvar int g[f in F];
  dvar float floorequ[i in F] in 0..0.99999;

  //MAIN objective functions
  dexpr float objmodel1 = sum(f in F) g[f];
  dexpr float objmodel2 = sum(n in Nodes, v in V) (Y[v][n] * cpuvnf[v] / Cpunode[n]);//to 
     minimize the use of cores
  dexpr float objmodel3 = sum(l in L, j in 1..2, f in F: nj[j] in Routes[f]) (IL[l][f][j] 
  [nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]] * landa[f] / C[l]); //to minimize the utilization of link capacities. 

  //New objective functions 
  dexpr float objmodel4 = sum(l in L, j in 1..2, f in F: nj[j] in Routes[f]) (IL[l][f][j] 
  [nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]] <= M * S[l]);//jitter
  dexpr float objmodel5 = sum(n in Nodes) G[n];//min capex
  dexpr float objmodel6 = sum(n in Nodes, v in V) Y[v][n]*Cpunode[n];//min opex

  maximize staticLex(objmodel1, objmodel2, objmodel3, objmodel4, objmodel5, objmodel6); 
  //........................................................................................

 subject to{

   forall (l in L)
    cons1: sum(j in 1..2, f in F: nj[j] in Routes[f]) (IL[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]] * 
           landa[f]) <= C[l];

forall (n in Nodes)
    cons2: sum(v in V) Y[v][n] * cpuvnf[v] <= Cpunode[n];//cpu

forall (n in Nodes)
    cons3: sum(v in V) Y[v][n] * memvnf[v] <= Memnode[n];//mem
    
forall (v in V, n in Nodes)
    cons4: sum(f in F, j in 1..2) I[v][n][f][j] * landa[f] <= u[v][n];
      
forall (n in Nodes, v in V, f in F, j in 1..2)
    cons5: Y[v][n] >= I[v][n][f][j];
              
forall (f in F, j in 1..2) 
    cons6: sum(n in Nodes, v in V) I[v][n][f][j] == 1;
   
forall (i in F)
    cons7: x[i]==g[i]+floorequ[i];   
                    
//Total delays

  forall (f in F)
    cons8: sum(l in L, j in 1..2: nj[j] in Routes[f]) IL[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]] * 
           Dlink[l] + sum(j in 1..2, v in V, n in Nodes) I[v][n][f][j] * Dvn[v][n] <= 
           Dflow[f];           

 //convert non_linear_equations to new linear constraints

  forall (j in 1..2, f in F: nj[j] in Routes[f], v in V) 
    cons9: sum(l in Lout[nj[j]]) z[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]][v] == 1;
   
forall (j in 1..2, f in F: nj[j] in Routes[f], l in Lout[nj[j]], v in V) {
    cons10: 3 * z[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]][v] <= (IL[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]] + I[v] 
            [nj[j]][f][j] + I[v][nj[j+1]][f][j+1]);
    cons11: z[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]][v] >= (IL[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]] + I[v] 
            [nj[j]][f][j] + I[v][nj[j+1]][f][j+1]) - 2; 
   }
                           
  //convert non_linear_equations to new linear constraints
   
    forall (j in 1..2, f in F: nj[j] in Routes[f], v in V) 
      cons12: sum(l in Lin[nj[j+1]]) z[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]][v] == 1;
   
    forall (j in 1..2, f in F: nj[j] in Routes[f], l in Lin[nj[j+1]], v in V) {          
      cons13: 3 * z[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]][v] <= (IL[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]] + 
              I[v][nj[j]][f][j] + I[v][nj[j+1]][f][j+1]);
      cons14: z[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]][v] >= (IL[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]] + I[v] 
              [nj[j]][f][j] + I[v][nj[j+1]][f][j+1]) - 2; }  
             
forall(j in 1..2, f in F: nj[j] in Routes[f], n in Nodes){
    cons15: sum(l in Lout[n]) IL[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]] <= 1;
    cons16: sum(l in Lin[n]) IL[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]] <= 1; }

forall (j in 1..2, f in F: nj[j] in Routes[f], n in Nodes)
  if(n != nj[j] && n != nj[j+1])
    cons17:  (sum(l in Lin[n]) IL[l][f][j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]]) - (sum(l in Lout[n]) IL[l][f] 
             [j][nj[j]][j+1][nj[j+1]]) == 0;        

forall (j in 1..2, f in F: nj[j] in Routes[f], v in V)  {    
    cons18: sum(l in Lout[nj[1]]) IL[l][f][1][nj[1]][2][nj[2]] == I[v][nj[2]][f][2];
    cons19: sum(l in Lin[nj[2]]) IL[l][f][1][nj[1]][2][nj[2]] == I[v][nj[2]][f][2]; }                       
          
forall (j in 1..2, f in F: nj[j] in Routes[f], v in V) {
    cons20: sum(l in Lin[nj[3]]) IL[l][f][2][nj[2]][3][nj[3]] == I[v][nj[2]][f][2]; 
    cons21: sum(l in Lout[nj[2]]) IL[l][f][2][nj[2]][3][nj[3]] == I[v][nj[2]][f][2]; }
                     
forall(n in Nodes)
    cons22: sum(v in V) Y[v][n] <= M * G[n];    
    }       
         
assert forall(f in F) g[f]==floor(x[f]);       

execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE {
    writeln("objmodel1==", objmodel1, " objmodel2==", objmodel2, " objmodel3==", objmodel3, " 
    objmodel4==", objmodel4, " objmodel5==", objmodel5 , " objmodel6==", objmodel6); }
```

.dat file

```
 Cpunode=[4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 10, 4]; 
 cpuvnf=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

 Memnode=[8, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 8, 16, 8];
 memvnf=[2, 2, 4, 4, 4];//or [1,4,8,8,8]

 u=[[10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10] 
    [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10] 
    [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]  
    [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]  
    [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]]; //5*9 matrix

 C=[1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 
    1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000];

 Dvn=[[0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003] 
      [0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003] 
      [0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003] 
      [0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003]  
      [0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003] ]; //5*9 matrix

 Dlink=[0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
        0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01];

 Dflow=[0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04,
        0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04,
        0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04,
        0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04,
       0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04];
```

Answer (score 0):

you could turn off warnings:

[image]

Or you could make sure that all the indexes in the arrays are used.

For instance

```
dvar int x[1..3];

subject to
{
  x[1]==1;
  x[3]==2;
}
```

give a warning about x[2] never used

whereas

```
{int} s={1,3};

dvar int x[s];

subject to
{
  x[1]==1;
  x[3]==2;
}
```

is OK

Comment: Hello, Mr Fleischer. Thanks a lot for your reply. I saw this example in stackoverflow site, but my problem is that my dimension's array is big like IL decision variable. How can I check it? Thanks for your help a million.